# What to replace entity_uri() with in Drupal 8?

Tags: 8

So I have the following code in my Drupal 7 module:

```
$uri = entity_uri('node', $node);
$breadcrumb[] = l($node->title, $uri['path'], $uri['options']);
```

Anyone know how to convert the above code to Drupal 8?

Since l() is depreciated, I believe the second line should be replaced as follows:

```
$breadcrumb = array(Link::createFromRoute($node->title, $uri['path'], $uri['options']));
```

I'm struggling with what to do with entity_uri() since the change records don't really indicate how that function is to be replaced.

Note: this is being used within the BreadcrumbBuilderInterface class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this code:

```
$link = $node->toLink($node->getTitle(), 'canonical', $options);
```

Get more information about Node object here: ["Node Object"](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!src!Entity!Node.php/class/Node/8/)

Comment: The entity_uri() function provides the $options, but where would I get those in the above example? Also looks like I may want to use toLink() instead as Entity::link() is depreciated.

Comment: toLink gives you an Link object, that has the options included.

Comment: Yes please change the answer to the following to get credit:
$link = $node->toLink($node->getTitle(), 'canonical', $options);

Comment: Yes please change the answer to the following to get credit:
`$link = $node->toLink($node->getTitle(), 'canonical', $options);` Part of the reason for this is the BreadcrumbBuilderInterface expects a Drupal\Core\Link object.

Comment: Get more information about Node object here: "Node Object" - This leads to a page with no helpful information. This should be either provided with correct link or should be removed.